# How and when Pentecost People raised in this world recently

Tags: pentecost, pentecostalism

Now a Days we can see the Independent Pentecostal churches all over the world. I want to know 
When these Pentecost people raised ???? till 19th century there is o news about that people

Comment: What are you asking? How did Pentecostalism start?

Comment: @Wikis Yes of course

Comment: Then I suggest you first [check out the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentacostal#History) and then come back if you have further *specific* questions.

Comment: Yes, the correct answer would just be a wikipedia summary.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is answered well enough from a Google search and Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

The Azusa Street Revival from 1906-1915 is almost universally accepted amongst Pentecostals to be the event in which the Holy Spirit revisited the church with the charismatic gifts of the early one. This included tongues.